# pip installation with different versions of python 3.x

Tags: python, python-3.x, ubuntu, pip

I have `python` `3.4.4`, `3.5.2` and `2.7` on my `Ubuntu` machine. I already have pip3 installed but it is for version `3.5.2`. I want to download `pip` for version `3.4.4` as this is the version I code in. I have seen the questions posted here on SO but none of them worked for me.

## Answer was found in another question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37723236/pip-error-while-installing-python-ignoring-ensurepip-failure-pip-8-1-1-requir)

Comment: Use `python3.4 -m pip <command> <options> <package/whatever>`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Pip suddenly using wrong version of Python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36311336/pip-suddenly-using-wrong-version-of-python)

Comment: gives me and error `no module named pip`

Comment: Then you'll need to install `pip` for Python 3.4 first.

Comment: If I knew how to do that I wouldn't post that question :).

Comment: Which Python 3 version is the one that Ubuntu maintains for you (i.e., which one did you not build yourself)?

Comment: both `2.7` and `3.5.2`.

Comment: Try `python3.4 -m ensurepip` first; see if that works. Otherwise, just follow the [pip installation guide](https://packaging.python.org/installing/#install-pip-setuptools-and-wheel).

Comment: `Ignoring ensurepip failure: pip 7.1.2 requires SSL/TLS` is what `python3.4 -m ensurepip` returns.

Comment: Then you'll need to reinstall Python 3.4 with the necessary ssl modules compiled. I assume that during building and installation, you ignored some packages & modules that weren't build?

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37723236/pip-error-while-installing-python-ignoring-ensurepip-failure-pip-8-1-1-requir

Comment: Yep, that worked. please add that as an answer so I can accept it.

Comment: I think it's more a duplicate of the linked question in my previous comment, isn't it?

Comment: Correct. It is. is there a way for me to mark it as a duplicate or should I remove the question? ( i'm still fresh to SO, so excuse my noobishness )

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/79916/is-it-possible-to-mark-my-own-question-as-duplicate-of-another (except for the comment "You need 250 rep to vote to close your own questions,"...)

Comment: yeah.. so what should I do ? I think you leaving an answer and me accepting it is the best solution ?

Comment: Leave it be. The current duplicate close vote is incorrect (due to unavailable information at the time) and can't be altered, but may attract further attention (and possibly pick up the correct duplicate). Flagging it is probably overkill and not done for this kind of issue. So all in all, I'd just leave the question as is.

Comment: Ookie dookie. thanks for your help.

Comment: You could [edit] your question to include a link to the actual duplicate (or possibly the answer itself). That'll be clearer for future readers.

Answer (score -2):

Change python path in `$PATH` to python3.4

`export PATH=/path/to/python3.4/bin:$PATH`

Comment: In the answer, I gave solution in case VirtualEnv won't work. Anyways edited answer to use python3.4 without VirtualEnv

Comment: If python path is changed to Python3.4, pip will also work for python3.4.. Pip for python3.4 would be located in python/3.4/site-packages

Comment: My problem is already solved by Evert. I needed to install some dependencies, reconfigure and recompile the installation. it works now. Thanks.